# How to get a value of a key in a twig array outside of a loop

Tags: php, arrays, twig

I have an array of states and a number like:

(state, count)

```
states=[
'ACT' => 25,
'NSW' => 45,
'VIC' => 18,
'SA'  => 12
]
```

I'm trying to get the value for each state in twig (outside of a loop).

So for each state (as a dynamic parameter) I need to get the "count" value:

```
{{ attribute(states, state_name).count }}
```

or

```
{{ attribute(states, count)}}
```

but not working.

Any idea?

**Edit:**
This code is working but can't get the value out of the loop.
In this code I need to run the loop several times.

```
{% for state in states %}
   {% if state.state_name == state_name %}
       ({{ state.count }})
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Something like `{{ attribute(states, state_name) }}`?

Comment: `{{ states[state_name] }}`?

Comment: sorry, none of them worked.

Answer (score 2):

There is no variable named `count`, you only have a key-value array where the value is the count. You can simply use `attribute` to get the value:

```
{{ attribute(states, state_name) }}
```

or, as jeroen commented:

```
{{ states[state_name] }}
```

Comment: count is the name of the key insidethe array [state_name, count]

Comment: @Ashkan what I meant is that you only have a key-value array, with the key as the `state_name` and the value as the `count`, thus to get the "count" you have to simply get the value: `states[state_name]`

Comment: {{ states[state_name] }}
this could make "ErrorException: Array to string conversion"